# Unable to move apps to SD card after Gingerbread upgrade

Tags: htc-desire

I upgraded my HTC Desire to Gingerbread via the official update yesterday. It wipes all settings, so I've been working through re-installing all the apps that I previously had on the phone. They all install fine and some move to the SD card fine too, but some just say "unable to move to SD card" when I select them. I suspect it's because they were on the SD card before and it's getting an error when trying to overwrite the existing files/directory. Where do these get stored and how can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, actually just tried again a few hours later and it works now... Odd!

Comment: I guess it is sorted now.

Comment: Yep, it's sorted. Not really an answer, but there we go...